# (Python 3): Scrapy MongoDB pipeline not working

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy

I am attempting to connect to MongoDB with a scrappy pipeline via Pymongo in order to create a new database and populate it with what I have just scraped, but I am running into a weird issue. I followed basic tutorials and set up 2 command lines, one to run scrapy in and the other to run mongod. Unfortunately when I run the scrapy code after running mongod, mongod does not appear to pick up on the scrapy pipeline I am trying to set up and just maintains a 'waiting for connections on port 27107' notice.

In command line 1 (scrapy) I set the directory as Documents/PyProjects/twitterBot/krugman

In command line 2 (mongod) I set it as Documents/PyProjects/twitterBot

The scripts I am using are as follows:
krugman/krugman/spiders/krugSpider.py (pulls paul krugman blog entries):

```
from scrapy import http
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
import scrapy
import pymongo
import json
from krugman.items import BlogPost


class krugSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'krugbot'
    start_url = ['https://krugman.blogs.nytimes.com']

    def __init__(self):
        self.url = 'https://krugman.blogs.nytimes.com/more_posts_jsons/page/{0}/?homepage=1&apagenum={0}'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield http.Request(self.url.format('1'), callback = self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        for block in range(len(data['posts'])):
            for article in self.parse_block(data['posts'][block]):
                yield article


        page = data['args']['paged'] + 1
        url = self.url.format(str(page))
        yield http.Request(url, callback = self.parse_page)


    def parse_block(self, content):
        article = BlogPost(author = 'Paul Krugman', source = 'Blog')                
        paragraphs = Selector(text = str(content['html']))

        article['paragraphs']= paragraphs.css('p.story-body-text::text').extract()
        article['links'] = paragraphs.css('p.story-body-text a::attr(href)').extract()
        article['datetime'] = content['post_date']
        article['post_id'] = content['post_id']
        article['url'] = content['permalink']
        article['title'] = content['headline']

        yield article
```

krugman/krugman/settings.py:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['krugman.pipelines.KrugmanPipeline']

MONGODB_SERVER = 'localhost'
MONGODB_PORT = 27017
MONGODB_DB = 'ScrapeDB'
MONGODB_TWEETS = 'tweetCol'
MONGODB_FACEBOOK = 'fbCol'
MONGODB_BLOG = 'blogCol'
```

krugman/krugman/pipelines.py

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy import log

class KrugmanPipeline(object):

    def __init(self):
        connection = MongoClient(settings['MONGODB_SERVER'], settings['MONGODB_PORT'])
        db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
        self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_BLOG']]

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.collection.insert_one(dict(item))
        log.msg("Test this out")
        return item
```

I'm not getting any error messages so I'm having difficulties troubleshooting. It seems like its just refusing to fire off at all. Any ideas as to what my problem could be?

Comment: i don't remember why I open connection in open_spider and close it in close_spider method, but its working

Answer (score 0):

In your settings, you didn't add MongoPipeline.

```
 ITEM_PIPELINES = {
     'crawler.pipelines.MongoPipeline': 800,
     'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 300,
 }
```

Comment: doesn't KrugmanPipeLine basically fulfill the same niche, since that what my pipeline object is called?

Comment: ah i didnt see that sorry